# How to use gradle for a project orchestration with keeping seperate repositories for every part of it

Tags: java, gradle

My application-solution contains of a client project and a server project. Both are hold in completely independent repositories.
I want now one big project which contains both parts so I can import it into my IDE and work on both at the same time but still can handle them as separate projects and seperate git repositories.

Also there are some model-classes in both projects. My idea is to move these resources into a new third project/repository and be able to use it in both repositories as imports. I have no idea how to realize this construction.

The main idea is, that every developer can decide if she/he will check out only the needed sub-project or the complete stack at once.
The resulting project structure should looks similar to this:

```
MyApp
|______ MyAppClient
|
|______ MyAppServer
|
|______ MyAppModel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [Composite Build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html).

Gradle will look at dependencies within a composite build and will use artifacts built within the composite when the group/artifact-id/version (GAV) matches a local project. For any dependencies which can't be found within the composite, Gradle will find the artifacts in the repository as normal